# Using windows service read/update SQL server 2008 R2

Tags: sql, windows-services, sql-server-2008-r2

I am new to Entity Framework (MVC) methodology, what I need to do is create a windows service that would query the table `messageinfo` in the database for a column `msgtype`.

`msgtype` that I am looking for is `10` (which translates as to be archived)

In such a case I need to move (not copy) the whole corresponding row to another table `backupmessageinfo`.

This has to be done using a windows service, which can be scheduled to run at specific time lets say 12 am every day.

Please help!

Any pointers much appreciated!!

Philip

Comment: 10 is the vlaue of the column msgtype that i want to scan for

Comment: A Windows service cannot be scheduled to run at certain times - it runs all the time. Maybe you need to write just a simple **console application** that *can* be scheduled for certain times instead

Answer (score 1):

IMHO you can achieve the desired result a lot easier utilizing SQL Server Agent for scheduling  and writing a simple sql script that will consist of `INSERT INTO ... SELECT FROM ...` and `DELETE` statements.